# Java Object Mapper: Mapping fields to first Object fields of a List of Objects java

Tags: java

I need to map a couple of fields to the fields of first object of List of Objects. Which Mapper API does provide this feature. I was looking at Dozer and a few but didn't find something of help.

```
class Person
{
  String fName;
  String lName;
....
}

class GenericPerson
{
  List<Name> name

....

}

Class Name
{
   String firstName
   String lastName;
   ......
}
```

So above if I have a person with `fName='Java'`, `lName='Oracle'` I need a list of `GenericPerson` with first object List(0): `firstName='java'`, `lastName='Oracle'`.

I realize it can be coded, but need for a lot of similar mappings.

Comment: Please elaborate on context in which you are working in. In Spring framework, for example, you can use https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService.html to convert from String to List<String>. If you are not writing your app using this framework. You can write your own converter class which will convert T to List<T> and call it whenever you need. That won't be so much coding with it.

Comment: I have a person class which has 25 fields and GenericPerson with similar number. There are similar classes I need mapping to.Above I need a conversion from String to List<Objects> with String fields. Yes I can write my own converter but just was trying to find out if there is a out-of-box way in Dozer or Spring which provides field level mapping of this type

Comment: Spring solution provides unified way to type conversion via ConversionService, but you still need to call it explicitly. BTW, if you are receiving some data from db, take a look at hibernate's AttributeConverter. https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/